# javascript: What's the difference between functionName() and functionName?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that you can reference a function with or without the parentheses. Why?, what's the difference?

As a slight aside, I've noticed this works:
`window.onload = functionName;`

Whereas this doesn't: 
`window.onload = functionName();`

Could anyone explain why the top line of code works and the bottom doesn't?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `()` version doesn't reference the function. It invokes the function and references its return value.

Given this function:

```
function functionName() {
    return "I'm a function";
}
```

This references the function:

```
 // window.onload will reference the function, and invoked it when the page loads
window.onload = functionName;
```

...but this references the string that was returned, which isn't very useful to `window.onload`:

```
 // the function is invoked immediately, so now window.onload references the
 //    string "I'm a function" that was returned
window.onload = functionName();
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing `func()` calls the function and evaluates to its value.

Writing `func` just evaluates to the function itself, without calling it.
(Just like writing `myVar` evaluates to its value)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions are [first class members](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) which means they can be treated much like other data types in language. For example, you can assign a function to a variable, pass it as an argument, return it from function etc.

Given this, `functionName` simply refers to the function object while `functionName()` invokes the function that is referenced by `functionName`.

---

This assigns the function refered to by `functionName` (which doesn't even have to be the actual function name, it could be a variable that was assigned to the function - an alias as it were! For example, `var functionName = myOtherFunction;` - this creates an alias for `myOtherFunction`)

```
window.onload = functionName;
```

while this invokes the function referenced by `functionName` and assigns it's result

```
window.onload = functionName();
```

Answer (score 0):

`functionName()` calls the function, then and there. On the other hand, `x = functionName` assigns the function 'functionName' to x. From that point onwards, calling x() is similar to calling functionName(). In the case of window.onload, your browser will call window.onload() when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

`functionName` is a name of variable holding reference to a function.
`functionName()` is an invocation of the function in that variable.